# Python split string by new line into list

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to split string by new line into list (without luck) my code process only first line of input other lines remains ignored...

my code

```
test = input("enter the case: ")

for test2 in test.split("/n"):
    test2 = test2.replace(" ", "")
    test2 = test2.replace(' ', '')
    test2 = list(test2)
    test2 = [int(i) for i in test2]
    print(test2)

    ans = 0
    for tes in test2[::2]:
        ans = (tes * 2)+ans
    for tes in test2[1::2]:
        ans = tes + ans

    if(ans%10==0):
        print("Real")
    else:
        print("Fake")
```

my input

```
1463 2372 5177 5080
5573 2395 5129 6315
0818 6626 6167 3009
2199 2359 2569 0736
3480 7343 5514 8613
5168 0377 0687 1070
```

and like i mentioned my code process only first line of input but i need that code process all lines of input.

Comment: It should be `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: already tried both /n and \n same result only first line is processed...

Comment: On the the side, `" "` and `' '` are the exact same thing.  Your second `.replace` is completely useless.

Comment: `input()` never returns something that includes new lines.  Hitting Enter ends `input`

Comment: I know that, but codeeval for some strange reason without one is printing error without one of replace...

Comment: but if "input()" never returns something that includes new lines, then how python know where is end of first line in my input? My print statment print(test2) returns >>> [1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 7, 7, 5, 0, 8, 0]

Comment: Try `'here'.split('\n')` in the Python shell.  It returns a list with one item: `'here'`.

Comment: Sorry for your time, now i get it :D what you want to say about input() statment